# What is best practices for syncing service cached Angular 1.3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am working on a legacy project with angular 1.3 and got stuck on a decision what is the best way to keep service variables and $scope in sync after updating or if receiving the data takes longer than the digest cycle.

I am implementing variable caching in my service, which returns a getter for a variable something like this:

```
return function () {
            if(!this.games)
            {
                this.games= [];
                if(!!this.gameTypeId)
                    this.getAll(this.gameTypeId);
                else
                    this.getAll();
            };
            return this.games;
        }
```

and if the getAll function takes longer than the digest cycle the view does not update. So a work around is to use $apply, but it feels that I am approaching this the wrong way. Because the promise looks like this:

```
return Resource.query({id: gameTypeId, resourceName: "Games/ByGameType"})
                    .$promise.then(function(response){
                        if(!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                angular.extend(this.games, response);
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            angular.extend(this.games, response);
                    });
```

And you have to check if the $digest cycle really ended (if the promise returns the value faster the the view updates on its own).

The other way is to sprinkle promise returns all around the controller and update the $scope.games there, on this side the controller gets little bit more crowded. And instead of returning a function in the getter just return a way to rebind $scope.games to service->this.games value. The first way is implemented now and works, but not sure if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
                    if(!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            angular.extend(this.games, response);
                        });
                    }
```

is unnecessary safety equipment. Angular `$q` promises are always executed on digest cycles.

`angular.extend` will mangle an array by combining older and newer elements. Unless this is the requirement, it should be

```
angular.copy(this.games, response);
```

Comment: I understand, this.games always gets updated. The problem is that $scope does not always reflect this change. And that happens if the $promise updates after the main $digest cycle ends. After that the promise just updates this.games and not the $scope. So I use the $apply for updating the view, since one of the $scope variables is set to the getter. So you are suggesting to update the $scope variable through promise.then() in the controller? By the way here i wrote a quick example: https://plnkr.co/edit/uTp5KZ401YfnXJrlQg0E?p=preview

Comment: Your example doesn't work because you use `setTimeout`. Replace a promise with Angular-friendly one($timeout, $http, resource), and it will. You never need to trigger digest during digest, and you're always on digest inside `then`.

Comment: For read-only model `games` array may be just returned from the model and bound to scope, as the original code is supposed to do (as long as you keep the reference to original array with `angular.copy`). For read/write model getters and setters are convenient.

Comment: setTimout is only used to immitate a long response time. If you would replace the getter function in the test controller with the other function (called longGameGetterFix) you would see it work.

Comment: @MattJ It isn't a 'fix' but a necessity. You always need `$apply` inside `setTimeout`, that's why `$timeout` is a shorter alternative (it is also good for testing). You never need `$apply` inside `$timeout` or `then` in $q promise. You never need `!$rootScope.$$phase` condition, because it is known if the code runs on digest or not. I guess this was a part of the question, so here's the answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! So basically nothing is needed to properly sync :D Just my own mistake...